# "Item not found" error while trying to access files in a folder on sharepoint using MS Graph api

Tags: python, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-files

I am trying to read the contents of a file present in a folder of a site in SharePoint using MS graph API.
When I am trying to read a file which is direct present on the site I am able to read it but unable to read the file which is present inside a folder on SharePoint.

For that I am receiving an error - Item not found.
The end point URL that I have been using so far is:

```http
/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/drive/root:/{site-name}/{folder-name}/{file-name}:/content
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get files in a folder content by

`/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/drive/root:/{folder-name}/{file-name}:/content` endpoint.